# MacBook won't read "heavy" discs

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

My MacBook's drive is typically fully functional (for most discs), but I've recently noticed that it refuses to read discs with a paint coat (such as most commercial software). What could have caused my MacBook to experience such an issue? (it didn't happen before).

Details: When inserted, the drive would spin up, seemingly as if nothing was wrong, but after about 15 seconds, it slows down. It repeats this a few times and eventually results in the disc being ejected.

Comment: What generation is your MBP? If it's an older one, mine too had this issue - it was down to the DVD drive. The DVD drives Apple ships with the MBPs are absolute rubbish. If you're a handy guy, you can easily replace this yourself.

Comment: MacBook Aluminum (late 2008) 4,1. It's such a strange problem, i don't see how it could occur over time.